# Debugging "crashed" top most window

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I have application that must run in Top most window. It works great till it crashes. When it crashes window becomes whiteis and windows crash window shows asking if you want to debug it.

In that moment I would like to use that option to debug that application. But I can't see anything because of that crashed topmost window.

I can't run application without topmost window. I can't attach debugger to application while it is running. My only possibility is to attach debugger after crash. But then I can't see anything.

Is there any way to "hide" crashed topmost window?

UPDATE:
I'm using WinApi.

Comment: Programmers that debug UI use two monitors.  You can use the remote debugger if you have only one.

Comment: The problem with your question (And the reason why nobody except noobs are answering you) is that you have not specified anything. Are you using standard C++? In that case, are you using a GUI framework like Qt, or the Win32 API directly? Please be more specific, edit your question and show us more context.

Comment: "It works great till it crashes."

Comment: There is no logical reason your application **must** use a top-most window during a debug session.  This seems like a self-imposed constraint and honestly it makes no sense what-so-ever.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious It is transparent overlay that runs above other application window. I don't want to go into details on why it is like that. But there is no way for this application to run not top most.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide a window using `ShowWindow(HWND,int)`:

If you have the handle of the window:

```
ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_HIDE);
```

If you only know the title:

```
HWND hwnd = FindWindowA(NULL,"Title");
ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_HIDE);
```

So when you want to do something but the crashed window is in the way, run these commands to hide it.

Comment: Window is crashed. It can not process messages.

Comment: Can't you bring the window you're working on to the front while the other one is crashed?

Comment: That is not a bad idea to try bring VS window to from instead.